# How to make search filters work when using multireference fields?

Tags: search, content-management-system, velo

I'm trying to create a search function that combines different filters. So far I can create a search bar and dropdown. But the moment I add a another filter say a checkbox or dropdown that uses multireference fields, and I test it, the search bar and/or dropdown is fine if I use them first. But the moment I use the filters with multireference fields, the search bar or drop down filter either shows no results or shows distorted results.

```
import { local } from 'wix-storage';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

//let experiancingThisChoices;

$w.onReady(function () {
    // Initialize the search when the page loads
    populateTitleFilterCheckbox();

    let savedSearchTerm = local.getItem("searchWord");
    $w("#searchBar").value = savedSearchTerm;

    
    $w('#dropDownCategory').value = local.getItem("category")
    
            const selectedExperiences = $w('#titleFilterCheckbox').value;
      local.setItem("imExperiencingThis", selectedExperiences);


    

    $w('#titleFilterCheckbox').onChange((event) => {
        // Update local storage and perform a new search
        const selectedExperiences = $w('#titleFilterCheckbox').value;
        console.log("selectedExperiancesOnChange", selectedExperiences)
        local.setItem("selectedExperiences", JSON.stringify(selectedExperiences));
        });

     $w('#showMoreButton').onClick(() => {
        $w('#statebox8').changeState("expanded");
    });

    $w('#showLessCollapse').onClick(() => {
        $w('#statebox8').changeState("collapsed");
    });

    $w('#dataset2').onReady(function () {

        search();
    });

    // Initially hide the collapsible section
    $w("#collapsibleStrip").collapse();


    if (savedSearchTerm) {
        $w("#searchBar").value = savedSearchTerm;
        // Do not perform the search here, just restore the saved search term
    }

    // Initially hide the collapsible section
    $w("#collapsibleStrip").collapse();

    // SEARCH BUTTON TRIGGER
    $w("#searchButton").onClick(function () {
        search();
    });

    // ENTER KEY TRIGGER
    $w("#searchBar").onKeyPress(function (event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            search();
        }
    });
}
);

// SEARCH FUNCTION
function search() {
    let searchTerm = $w("#searchBar").value;
    let selectedCategory = $w("#dropDownCategory").value;
    let selectedExperiences = JSON.parse(local.getItem("selectedExperiences") || '[]');

    console.log("selectedExperiances", selectedExperiences);

    local.setItem("searchWord", searchTerm);
    $w("#loadingGif").show();
    
    let query = wixData.query('MentalHealth');

    // Only add contains filter if searchTerm is not empty
    if (searchTerm) {
        query = query.contains('title', searchTerm)
                .or(wixData.query('MentalHealth').contains('sessionType', searchTerm));
    }
    
    // Apply category filter only if selectedCategory is not empty
    if (selectedCategory) {
        query = query.eq('category', selectedCategory);
    }
        
        // Filter by experiences (multi-reference field)
    if (selectedExperiences.length > 0) {
        query = query.hasSome('imExperiencingThis', selectedExperiences);
    }


    query.find()
        .then(res => {
            $w('#repeater1').data = res.items;
            updateResultText(res.items.length);
            $w("#loadingGif").hide();
            if (res.items.length > 0) {
                $w("#repeater1").scrollTo();
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Search failed:", err);
            $w("#loadingGif").hide();
        });
}

function updateResultText(count) {
    let text = count === 1 ? "1 result was found." : `${count} results were found.`;
    if (count === 0) text = "No result found!";
    $w('#textResults').text = text;
    $w('#textResults').show();
}

export function filterCollapseButton_click(event) {
    toggleBox($w('#collapsibleStrip'));
}

function toggleBox(boxElement) {
    if (boxElement.collapsed) {
        boxElement.expand();
    } else {
        boxElement.collapse();
    }
}


//Reset Filter

export function resetFilterButton_click(event) {
 $w("#dataset2").setFilter(wixData.filter())

    $w("#searchBar").value = undefined;
    $w("#dropDownCategory").value = undefined;
    $w("#titleFilterCheckbox").value = undefined;
        
}


async function populateTitleFilterCheckbox() {
    const experiancingThisQueryResult = await wixData.query("experiencingThis").find();
    console.log("query result", experiancingThisQueryResult)
    const experiancingThisChoices = experiancingThisQueryResult.items;
    const checkboxOptions = experiancingThisChoices.map((choice)=>({
        label: choice.title, 
        value: choice._id
    }))

    $w("#titleFilterCheckbox").options = checkboxOptions;
}
```

Comment: I think I made it work when I added:

```session.removeItem("example");```

It's to remove from temp storage